# Trigger Jenkins builds remotely via Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create Jenkins pipelines via Groovy script. How do I enable the checkbox `Trigger builds remotely` via Groovy script. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is to use Job DSL plugin. When it's installed, you can view documentation via the following link

**https://<your.jenkins.installation>/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html**

There, under `pipelineJob`, you'll find `triggers` documentation